# How to Remove Files You Meant to Ignore from Staging Area of Git Repo

Tags: git

If you forget to add something to .gitignore, for instance, test-output/ and you review your changes and see the files got into the staging area through a

```
git add .
```

adding test-output/ to .gitignore and then adding that to the commit does not make the files disappear from the staging area. Furthermore, attempting to remove them with

```
git rm -r test-output/
```

is disallowed. In this case, I was able to just remove the folder and do add again. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unstage the folder `test-output` by doing

```
git reset HEAD test-output
```